# Upload fichero a carpeta y posterior envio email php

Tags: php, laravel, sql, fileupload

Hola a todos estoy tratando de hacer una subida de un fichero, con un formulario a una carpeta para un posterior envio de email. Mi problema es que desde html y php puro lo consigo sin problemas, pero necesito capturar IDs de clientes en datalist rellenados con ajax y eso con PHP no se puede, tengo que hacerlo con javascript (jquery) por lo tanto he tenido que dar un paso atrás en mi desarrollo y volver a una versión anterior donde si insertaba sin problemas en la BD, el problema es capturar el input type file con el nombre del fichero (en la bd se guarda la ruta) Estoy trabajando con Laravel y usando $request->file('adjunto') pero siempre me viene vacio... Como debo de capturar el file del input para pasarlo al controlador¿??

JS:

```
// función para insertar la incidencia
function insertarIncidencia(codigoCliente){

    var fechaSolicitud = $("#fechaSolicitud").val();
    var categoria = $("#categoria").val();
    var solicitante = $("#idSolicitante").val();

    var prioridad = $("#Abrirprioridad").val();
    var asunto = $("#asunto").val();
    var mensaje = $("#cuerpoMensaje").val();
    var adjunto = $("#adjunto").val();
    var token = $("#token").val();


    $.ajax({
        url: '/setIncidencia',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "fechaSolicitud": fechaSolicitud,
            "categoria": categoria,
            "solicitante": solicitante,
            "prioridad": prioridad,
            "cliente": codigoCliente,
            "asunto": asunto,
            "mensaje": mensaje,
            "adjunto": adjunto,
            "_token": token
        },

        success:function (data) {
            $("#correcto").show();
            $("#correcto").append("Incidencia Generada");

            console.log(data);
            
            // ENVIAMOS EL ID DE LA ULTIMA INCIDENCIA INSERTADA Y TAMBIÉN
            // CUANDO ENVIEMOS EL EMAIL, NOS DEVOLVERÁ A LA PÁGINA DE LAS INCIDENCIAS
            //enviarEmailTecnicos(data);
        },
        error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            $("#error").append(xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.status);
        }
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
public function setIncidenciaPost(Request $request){

    $uploadedFile = "";
    $filename = "";

    echo "fichero: " . $request['adjunto'];
    exit();

    if($request->file('adjunto') != ""){
        $uploadedFile = $request["adjunto"];
        $filename = $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();

        \Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs(
            'subidas/'.$filename,
            $uploadedFile,
            $filename
        );
    }else{
        echo "viene vacio";
    }


    $resultado = \DB::table('incidencias')->insert([
                                        'fecha_solicitud' => $request["fechaSolicitudAbrir"],
                                        'fecha_respuesta' => $request["fechaRespuesta"],
                                        'categoria' => $request["categoria"],
                                        'solicitante' => $request["solicitante"],
                                        'prioridad' => $request["prioridad"],
                                        'estado' => "pendiente",
                                        'asunto' => $request["asunto"],
                                        'cuerpo' => $request["mensaje"],
                                        'cliente' => $request["cliente"],
                                        'adjunto' => $request->file('adjunto')
                                    ]);

    $idIncidencia = \DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

    // ENVIA EMAIL A LOS TÉCNICOS CUANDO SE GENERA LA INCIDENCIA
    //$this->enviarEmail($request);

return \Redirect::to('/mostrarIncidencias');

}
```

Como se puede observar, hay código de prueba, pero ni con file ni con el request puro consigo el file... El request, me devuelve la ruta completa... Y con File siempre va vacio...

FORMULARIO HTML

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="mt-5 pl-5 pr-5" id="formularioAlta" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row offset-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fechaSolicitud">Fecha de solicitud</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 pb-5">
                                <input type="text" name="fechaSolicitudAbrir" id="fechaSolicitud" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group pl-5">
                            <label for="fechaSolicitud">Categoria</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="categoria" id="categoria">
                                    <option selected>Selecione unca categoria</option>
                                    <option value="Comercial">Comercial</option>
                                    <option value="Técnico">Técnico</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- FIN PRIMER ROW -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                    <label for="fechaSolicitud">Solicitante</label>
                                    <br/>
                                    <!-- ESCRIBIMOS EL NOMBRE DE QUIEN SOLICITA LA INCIDENCIA -->
                                    <input type="text" name="solicitante" id="solicitante" value="{{auth()->user()->nombre}}"/>

                                    <!-- ESCRIBIMOS LA ID DEL USUARIO QUE HA INICIADO LA SESIÓN, PARA HACER OPERACIONES POSTERIORMENTE-->
                                    <input type="hidden" name="idSolicitante" id="idSolicitante" value="{{auth()->user()->cod_usuario}}"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                    <label for="fechaSolicitud">Prioridad</label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                        <select class="browser-default custom-select" id="Abrirprioridad" name="Abrirprioridad">
                                            <option selected>Seleccione una prioridad</option>
                                            <option value="Urgente">Urgente</option>
                                            <option value="Inmediato">Inmediato</option>
                                            <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 pb-3">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                        <label for="cliente">Cliente:</label><br>
                                        <input type="text" list="clientes" id="nombreClienteAbrir" name="cliente"/>
                                            <datalist id="clientes"></datalist>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- FIN SEGUNDO ROW -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <label for="asunto">Persona Contacto:</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreContacto" name="nombre">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <label for="asunto">Telefono Contacto:</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefonoContacto" name="telefono">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <label for="asunto">Asunto</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" list="asuntosAbrir" name="asunto" id="asunto"/>
                                <datalist id="asuntosAbrir"></datalist>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <label for="mensaje">Mensaje</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="cuerpoMensaje" name="mensaje"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 mt-3">
                            <label for="mensaje">Adjunto</label>
                            <input type="file" name="adjunto" id="adjunto">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- input para el token -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="enviarIncidencia" value="Enviar incidencia">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Agradezco toda ayuda.

**RESUELTO**

*Controlador:*

```
// FUNCIÓN PARA ABRIR UNA INCIDENCIA

public function setIncidenciaPost(Request $request){

    $uploadedFile = "";
    $filename = "";




    if($request->file('adjunto') != ""){
        $uploadedFile = $request->file('adjunto');
        $filename = $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();

        //$subido = \Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs(public_path(), $uploadedFile, $filename);
        $destino = 'subidas';
        $uploadedFile->move($destino, $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName());

    }else{
        echo "archivo vacio";
        exit();
    }


    //consulta para obtener el ID del cliente, a traves del nombre que se eligió en el datalist
    $cliente = \DB::table('usuarios')->where("nombre", '=', $request["cliente"])->first();

    

    $resultado = \DB::table('incidencias')->insert([
                                        'fecha_solicitud' => $request["fechaSolicitudAbrir"],
                                        'fecha_respuesta' => $request["fechaRespuesta"],
                                        'categoria' => $request["categoria"],
                                        'solicitante' => $request["idSolicitante"],
                                        'prioridad' => $request["Abrirprioridad"],
                                        'estado' => "pendiente",
                                        'asunto' => $request["asunto"],
                                        'cuerpo' => $request["mensaje"],
                                        'cliente' => $cliente->cod_usuario,
                                        'adjunto' => $filename
                                    ]);

    $idIncidencia = \DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

    // ENVIA EMAIL A LOS TÉCNICOS CUANDO SE GENERA LA INCIDENCIA
    $this->enviarEmail($request);

return \Redirect::to('/mostrarIncidencias');
```

*JS*

```
   // función para insertar la incidencia
function insertarIncidencia(codigoCliente){

    var fechaSolicitud = $("#fechaSolicitud").val();
    var categoria = $("#categoria").val();
    var solicitante = $("#idSolicitante").val();

    var prioridad = $("#Abrirprioridad").val();
    var asunto = $("#asunto").val();
    var mensaje = $("#cuerpoMensaje").val();
    var token = $("#token").val();
    var adjunto = $('#adjunto').prop('files')[0];


    $.ajax({
        url: '/setIncidencia',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "fechaSolicitud": fechaSolicitud,
            "categoria": categoria,
            "solicitante": solicitante,
            "prioridad": prioridad,
            "codigoCliente": codigoCliente,
            "asunto": asunto,
            "mensaje": mensaje,
            "adjunto": adjunto,
            "_token": token
        },
        success:function (data) {
            $("#correcto").show();
            $("#correcto").append("Incidencia Generada");

            console.log(data);
            
            // ENVIAMOS EL ID DE LA ULTIMA INCIDENCIA INSERTADA Y TAMBIÉN
            // CUANDO ENVIEMOS EL EMAIL, NOS DEVOLVERÁ A LA PÁGINA DE LAS INCIDENCIAS
            //enviarEmailTecnicos(data);
        },
        error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            $("#error").append(xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.status);
        }

});
```

}

Comment: y como debería de hacerlo en Laravel?

Comment: Hola. Todo lo puedes hacer con php los controladores laravel son objetos php. Y, **se presume** que laravel facilita la escritura de código php. Las superglobales como $_POST **no han desaparecido** por el hecho de usar el framework. Si sabes php puedes usarlo dentro de los controladores con entera libertad.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. He usado $_POST['adjunto'] y viene vacio.... estoy usando este fragmento de código var adjunto = $('#adjunto').prop('files')[0]; pero me provoca un error 405 en laravel y desconozco porqué. El caso es que usando ese fragmento de código si obtengo el nombre de fichero y dice que es un File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controlador:

```
// FUNCIÓN PARA ABRIR UNA INCIDENCIA

public function setIncidenciaPost(Request $request){

    $uploadedFile = "";
    $filename = "";

    if($request->file('adjunto') != ""){
        $uploadedFile = $request->file('adjunto');
        $filename = $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();

        //$subido = \Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs(public_path(), $uploadedFile, $filename);
        $destino = 'subidas';
        $uploadedFile->move($destino, $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName());

    }else{
        echo "archivo vacio";
        exit();
    }


    //consulta para obtener el ID del cliente, a traves del nombre que se eligió en el datalist
    $cliente = \DB::table('usuarios')->where("nombre", '=', $request["cliente"])->first();

    $resultado = \DB::table('incidencias')->insert([
                                        'fecha_solicitud' => $request["fechaSolicitudAbrir"],
                                        'fecha_respuesta' => $request["fechaRespuesta"],
                                        'categoria' => $request["categoria"],
                                        'solicitante' => $request["idSolicitante"],
                                        'prioridad' => $request["Abrirprioridad"],
                                        'estado' => "pendiente",
                                        'asunto' => $request["asunto"],
                                        'cuerpo' => $request["mensaje"],
                                        'cliente' => $cliente->cod_usuario,
                                        'adjunto' => $filename
                                    ]);

    $idIncidencia = \DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

    // ENVIA EMAIL A LOS TÉCNICOS CUANDO SE GENERA LA INCIDENCIA
    $this->enviarEmail($request);

return \Redirect::to('/mostrarIncidencias');
JS

   // función para insertar la incidencia
function insertarIncidencia(codigoCliente){

    var fechaSolicitud = $("#fechaSolicitud").val();
    var categoria = $("#categoria").val();
    var solicitante = $("#idSolicitante").val();

    var prioridad = $("#Abrirprioridad").val();
    var asunto = $("#asunto").val();
    var mensaje = $("#cuerpoMensaje").val();
    var token = $("#token").val();
    var adjunto = $('#adjunto').prop('files')[0];


    $.ajax({
        url: '/setIncidencia',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "fechaSolicitud": fechaSolicitud,
            "categoria": categoria,
            "solicitante": solicitante,
            "prioridad": prioridad,
            "codigoCliente": codigoCliente,
            "asunto": asunto,
            "mensaje": mensaje,
            "adjunto": adjunto,
            "_token": token
        },
        success:function (data) {
            $("#correcto").show();
            $("#correcto").append("Incidencia Generada");

            console.log(data);
            
            // ENVIAMOS EL ID DE LA ULTIMA INCIDENCIA INSERTADA Y TAMBIÉN
            // CUANDO ENVIEMOS EL EMAIL, NOS DEVOLVERÁ A LA PÁGINA DE LAS INCIDENCIAS
            //enviarEmailTecnicos(data);
        },
        error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            $("#error").append(xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.status);
        }

});
}
```